# Moderncv error ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\end@ \end

Tags: moderncv, compilation-error

I'm very new to LaTeX and I have that same error while computing my resume and I can't find the solution anywhere on the web.
I go two errors on the 44th line (the `\end{document}` line):

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\end@ \end
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].\csuse #1->\ifcsname #1\endcsname \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \fi \end
```

Can you help me with this please? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.6cm, right=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.7cm}
\firstname{xxxxxxxx}
\familyname{xxxxxx}
\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxx / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\address{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\email{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx}
\mobile{06 00 00 00 00}
\extrainfo{21 ans}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace*{-2.5\baselineskip}
\section{Expériences}
\cventry{juillet 2016}{Auxiliaire d'été}{La Banque Postale, Centre National 
  de mise en relation}{Paris}{France}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Gestion de des flux téléphoniques\texttt{/}Préparation du budget 2017
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{Septembre 2015\\à Juin 2016}{Missions d'hôte diverses}{Agence 
  Allure}{Paris}{France}{
\begin{itemize}%
\item Distribution de flyers pour divers prestatires en région parisienne 
\item Soirée Orange à la FIAC au Grand Palais
\item Nuit de la Voix à la salle Gaveau, Paris
\end{itemize}}
\section{Formations}
\cventry{Septembre 2018 -- Aujourd'hui}{Master in Economics}{}{}{Master co- 
  dirigé par l'Ecole Normale Supérieure Paris Saclay, L'Ecole Polytechnique, 
  Université Paris-Sud, HEC}{}
\cventry{Septembre 2017 -- Aujourd'hui}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} 
  {Ecole Normale Paris-Saclay, Cachan}{}{}{}
\cventry {2015 -- 2017}{Licence de Mathématique et informatique appliqués 
  aux sciences humaines et sociales}{Université Paris-Nanterre}{}{}{}
\cventry{2015 -- 2017}{Classe Préparatoire Ecole Normale Supérieure Paris- 
  Saclay D2}{Ecole Nationale de Commerce, Paris}{}{}{}
\cventry{2015}{Baccalauréat série S}{Lycée xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
  xxxxxxxxxxxxx}{}{}{}
\section{Certifications}
\cventry{Mars 2018}{Certification Anglais C1 }{Cambridge Exam}{}{}{}
\section{Compétences en informatique et langues}
\cvitem{\underline{Programmation}}{SQL, R}
\cvitem{\underline{Analyse de données}}{MySQL, Stata, R}
\cvlanguage{\underline{Anglais}}{lu, écrit, parlé}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\cvlanguage` command has 3 arguments, and you passed only 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments, due to a missing argument to `\cvlanguage`.